# Inserting into nested map in C++

Tags: c++

Assume I have a nested map of type pointer. Then is there a single line statement to insert into the nested map,

```
map<int, map<int, int> >* nestedMap;
```

Currently I am doing this in 2 steps. First creating innermap and then insert into outer map as below,

```
nestedMap->insert(make_pair(int, map<int, int>)(int, innermap));
```

If the map is not pointer type, then i can insert easily like this,

```
nestedMap[int][int] = int;
```

Is there any simple ways for inserting into nested map of type pointer ?

thanks
Prabu

Comment: I think this is enough easy - just a single line on code. For better reading - I suggest you to make a class Map <T, T>, then method `bool insert(T, T)` (something like a wrapper of this ugly line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map::operator[]` **automatically** creates the key/value pair if it doesn't exist.
(That's why it's not const!)
So you don't need to create the inner map manually.

If you want to *avoid* creating the pair automatically, then use `map::find()` or `map::at()`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the simplest one-liner is:

```
(*nestedMap)[int][int] = int;
```

Answer (score 1):

access the `operator[]` via `->`:

```
nestedMap->operator[](5)[6] = 7;
```

This is analogous to

```
nestedMap[5][6] = 7;
```

if `nestedMap` is not a pointer.

Note that in neither case do you have to explicitly insert a map.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question properly, you can actually use reference instead of pointer. You are not having issue with nested map, instead your outter map.

See below code, is what you want?

```
map<int, map<int, int> >* nestedMap  = new map<int, map<int, int> >;   
map<int, map<int, int> > &nestedMapAlais = *nestedMap;
nestedMapAlais[1][2] = 3;
```

Comment: So far I thought we can't insert via (*nestedMap)[][], so only i raised this question. Now it clears. Thanks for your information